# What do people normally call a glass walled lab or room?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I remember reading Dan Brown's *The Lost Symbol* and coming across a word that was used to call one of Katherine lab/research rooms.
I can't remember what it is, and this really bugs me.
Does anyone know this word? (Or at least understand what I'm talking about?)

Edit:
Maybe it doesn't even have to be glass walled. Just any kind of lab or just a room.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Cleanroom maybe? We'll need some more context. What kind of research did Katherine do perhaps. Are you sure this word is specific to labs?

Comment: She does research in Noetic field but I don't think it's relevant cuz I came across the word more than one time. One in Dan Brown's and the other when someone was talking about a glass walled conference room in a Start-up incubator.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about remembering what word was used for a particular situation in a particular book. It is not about the English language.

Comment: Why not **read** it one more time? And **see** it here: http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2009/09/photogalleries/lost-symbol-dan-brown-pictures/photo2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pod? If I remember correctly...

Comment: OMG!! yess!!!!!! Thank you!!!! otherwise this would bug me all night!!!!

Comment: @CuriousLearner just so you know, this is not used to describe labs, you won't be understood if you refer to one as a pod. abcXYZ nice catch, +1!

Comment: @terdon lol I swear I didn't know this was referring to a lab either. It's more like a small working cube or something, but I read that part in Dan Brown and was kinda puzzled wondering what he was referring to.

Comment: Well, it's Dan Brown, don't expect [any kind of accuracy](http://www.historyversusthedavincicode.com/). And I'm not saying this out of any religious sensibilities, the man has apparently never read a history book.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read the book but are you referring to a [***terrarium***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/terrarium)?

Labs are sometimes referred to as ***cubes*** (after *cubicles*).

Comment: Hey @user49727 Thanks, but I don't think it's the word I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

There are many varieties of glasses : just to have an aseptic space with natural light, or to protect from infra-red, or UV, or even X-ray, to get only one specific color, to protect from possible explosion during a dangerous experiment, to keep a specific pressure, or a definite composition of gases, ... Some have to be air-tight, some not ; some forbid even microscopic dust, some not. Etc..

Every one has a specific name.

Why not keep a general term if you have not to be accurate : "glass-room, "glassed room", or "glass-cubicle" according to the size ?